# Is there any downside to using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

Can someone please explain to me the downside of using **create-react-app** compared to creating you own boiler plate react application?

Comment: if you have your own particular custom way of wanting to structure an app, you may be inconvenienced to refactor things when c-r-a has done its business. You may also feel dirty by using a facebook product

Comment: Not that I can think of? The only downside that would come to mind is you would have to delete the boilerplate files that you don't want and restructure the folder if you went the `create-react-app` route thus taking up more of your time?

Comment: @illiteratewriter Sorry about. I google the question and most of them took me to articles about the advantages and disadvantages of create-react-app. I wanted some inputs from a couple of React developers and I never saw that subreddit before. Now on I will use r/reactjs to search my questions. Thank you.